# Lambda not implementing sleep function properly python

Tags: python, python-3.x, aws-lambda

I'm using sleep inside my lambda function, to make it sleep for 4 minutes

```
import time

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print("hi")
    time.sleep(240)
    print("bye")
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps('Hello from Lambda!')
    }
```

Getting this

Calling the invoke API action failed with this message: Network Error

but execution of lambda is getting completed in 1 second, any specific reason for this.

I know it is not the best practice to use sleep in lambda, but I have a special requirement

Comment: can you provide the complete code of the lambda function?

Comment: can't share the full code, but updated the code snippet

Answer (score 2):

The default timeout for a Lambda is 3 seconds. To update, go to the Lambda console and select your Lambda. Then scroll down a bit to "Basic Settings". Select that:

[image]

And update as you need.  You may want to give it a bit more than 4 minutes exactly.

If you're using the aws cli, you can run something like:

`aws lambda update-function-configuration --function-name functionName --timeout 240`

to change the Lambda function functionName to have a 240 second timeout.

Comment: I have updated it to 10 min, still getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

When calling a function from Lambda, you have to specify its parameters. Your function takes 2 parameters. Consider iterating over inputs from iterable a and calling for each set of parameters with lambda:

```
import time
import json

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print("hi")
    time.sleep(3)
    print("bye")
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps('Hello from Lambda!')
    }

a = [('contxt1', 'evt1'), (('contxt2', 'evt2'))]

b = list(map(lambda x: lambda_handler(x[0], x[1]), a))

print(b)
```

Comment: for for three seconds it is working fine, but when you scale it for 3 min or 4 min , it is giving me ---  Calling the invoke API action failed with this message: Network Error

Comment: Are you calling it via web api? Then your connection will time out and you should look into background workers like redis or flask-executor. That is a different problem where you can look at this simple binding for light use cases https://flask-executor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: No, not calling via any api, it just an aws s3 event based trigger that would trigger the aws glue job latter on

Comment: if you run this over console it works fine. The problem you are looking at in your case is because of network invocation. The status code and body shows that it is an HTTP invocation that s3 trigger is doing internally. That is a different problem altogether.

Comment: For more reading about keep-alives and timeout. If you have control over this value, i suggest you experiment with it https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-thomson-hybi-http-timeout-03#section-2

Comment: I'm testing it why console, don't know why I'm getting this error, I have also increased the timeout to 10 min.

Comment: I am not sure we are talking about the same timeout, but you should open another question with that one. You wont be able to solve it here.